# Add UserControl to a variable location in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2012

So I am trying to add a UserControl to a windows form, however I want to add it in a variable location when a button is clicked.

So I have a groupbox in one location and I want the first one to go to the extreme left directly under the groupbox, I then want the next one to be in a position relative to the first, and all subsequent ones to be in a position in relation to the one before. However with restricted space a new line of these controls would have to be eventually created.

I am not sure if this is possible, or how I would do it. Currently I only know how to define a specific point for the control to be created at.

The only part of the code that really matters:

```
private void addpilot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PilotControl newPilot = new PilotControl();
    newPilot.Location = new Point();
    this.Controls.Add (newPilot);
}
```

Comment: You should try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y62k236c.aspx and make sure you check FlowDirection property

Comment: I'm maybe dump, but I think you should replace this by the name of your GroupBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this behavior could be similar to a `WrapPanel`. If it is not, you may try to solve this using another Panel, or also, implementing your own panel to create an specific location behavior.
Try seen Panels Overview in the MSDN.

Comment: I have figured it out, I am now using a flow pannel.

Comment: Panels are greats!! You can do good things making custom panels.

Comment: If this answer is the useful for you, can you mark it as the selected one? :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into docking and flow controls.